# Why is weight of 1 mole of substance equal to atomic/molecular mass in grams?

Tags: mole

> Why is weight of 1 mole of substance equal to atomic/molecular mass in grams?

According to me, it happens because mole has been defined in such a way. It is defined as the numbers of particles in $\pu{12 g}$ of $\ce{^{12}C}$. If it were $\pu{24 g}$ instead of $\pu{12 g}$, then the weight of 1 mole of substance would equal 2 times the atomic/molecular mass in grams.

Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere (or maybe everywhere).

Comment: Yes, you are basically correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why is weight of 1 mole of substance equal to atomic/molecular mass in grams?
>
> According to me, it happens because mole has been defined in such a way.

Yes! That is correct.

> It is defined as the numbers of particles in 12 g of C12. If it were 24 g, instead of 12 g, then the weight of 1 mole of substance would equal 2 times the atomic/molecular mass in grams.

Also correct, assuming that the definition of **unified atomic mass units** (amu) remained the same. @Martin's answer is correct, but we can also arrive at the same conclusion using a simple dimensional analysis approach.

First we need the definition of an amu:

$$\pu{1 atom}~ \ce{^12C} = \pu{12 amu}$$

Now take the real definition of a mole:

$$\pu{1 mol}~ \ce{^12C} = \pu{12 g}$$

Now, divide the first equation by the second:

$$\frac{\pu{1 atom}~ \ce{^12C}}{\pu{1 mol}~ \ce{^12C}} = \frac{\pu{12 amu}}{\pu{12 g}}$$

Cross-multiply and reduce:

$$1~\frac{\pu{g}}{\pu{mol}~ \ce{^12C}} = 1~\frac{\pu{amu}}{\pu{atom}~ \ce{^12C}}$$

What this tells us is that the **ratio** of g/mol to amu/atom is exactly one - and we made sure it would work out that way by carefully choosing how we defined moles and amus.

Since the masses of *all* elements are defined in terms of amu, which are ultimately based on the mass relative to carbon-12, this ratio holds for all any atom or molecule.

Let's take it further and put in your hypothetical doubling of the number of grams of carbon-12 per mole:

$$\frac{\pu{1 atom}~ \ce{^12C}}{\pu{1 mol}~ \ce{^12C}} = \frac{\pu{12 amu}}{\pu{24 g}}$$

Now when we cross-multiply and reduce, we get:

$$2~\frac{\pu{g}}{\pu{mol}~ \ce{^12C}} = 1~\frac{\pu{amu}}{\pu{atom}~ \ce{^12C}}$$

Since we kept the definition of an amu the same, but changed that of the mole, what we see is that 1 mole of carbon-12 using these units would have to weigh 24 g (the *molar mass*), even though its *atomic mass* would still be 12.

That's a lot harder to keep track of mentally, and so it is a good thing for us that the definitions of amus and moles were chosen so carefully!

Comment: Avogadro's constant is the inverse of 1 amu...How is that related to mole concept?

Comment: The definitions of moles and a.m.u. in combination, yes.

Comment: The use of the atomic mass unit is deprecated, it should be used the [unified atomic mass unit](http://goldbook.iupac.org/U06554.html). What is the difference? Amu was based on $\ce{^{16}O}$.

Comment: @Martin you are right about that - typically today, a.m.u. refers to the unified atomic mass unit. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Actually $\mathrm{u}$ refers to the unified atomic mass, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: "It is defined as the numbers of particles in 12 g of C12. If it were 24 g, instead of 12 g, then"**the $\mathrm{(a.m.u)}~\text{in grams}=\frac{\pu{1 g}}{3.01\times{10^{23}}}$**

Comment: Shouldn't it be written $\text{mass(1 atom}{}^{12}C\text{)}=12\text{amu}$ and likewise for the next line, considering that one carbon-12 atom is not really equivalent to 12 a.m.u?

Answer (score 9):

***In short terms:***

Your assumption is correct. If the definition of mole would have been based on 24 grams of carbon-12, all molecular weights would double. This is not the case and I highly doubt, that this definition will ever change.

---

***In long terms:***

This question is very definition specific. One should not be confused with the several types of definitions. All these definitions are based on the carbon-12 isotope. Hence the [atomic mass (constant)](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00497.html) has a specific value:

> One twelfth of the mass of a carbon-12 atom in its nuclear and
>   electronic ground state,  $m_u = 1.660 5402 10~\times~10^{−27}~\text{kg}$. It is equal
>   to the unified atomic mass unit.

The [unified atomic mass unit](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00497.html) is therefore a derived non-SI unit:

> Non-SI unit of mass (equal to the atomic mass constant), defined as
>   one twelfth of the mass of a carbon-12 atom in its ground state and
>   used to express masses of atomic particles,  $u\approx 1.660 5402 10~\times~10^{−27}~\text{kg}$.

The atomic weight (i.e. [relative atomic mass](http://goldbook.iupac.org/R05258.html)) is a ratio (=number) and therefore has no unit:

> The ratio of the average mass of the atom to the unified atomic mass
>   unit.

Also based on carbon-12 is the [definition of mole](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M03980.html), which you stated correctly:

> SI base unit for the amount of substance (symbol:  mol). The mole is
>   the amount of substance of a system which contains as many elementary
>   entities as there are atoms in 0.012 kilogram of carbon-12. When the
>   mole is used, the elementary entities must be specified and may be
>   atoms, molecules, ions, electrons, other particles, or specified
>   groups of such particles.

Derived from this is the [Avogadro constant](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00543.html):

> Fundamental physical constant (symbols: $L$,  $N_A$) representing the
>   molar number of entities:  $L = 6.022 141 79 30 \times 10^{23}~\text{mol}^{−1}$.

---

Therfore one can derive several other commonly used properties, such as molecular mass and molar mass. In a biannual publication "[Atomic weights of the elements](http://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/series/atomicweights/)" are published by IUPAC. In [Pure Appl. Chem., 2013, Vol. 85, No. 5, pp. 1047-1078](http://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/85/5/1047/) (or [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/PAC-REP-13-03-02)) it says:

> The **atomic mass**, $m_\text{a}$, of an unbound neutral atom of
>   carbon-12, $m_\text{a}(\ce{{}^{12}C})$, in its nuclear and electronic
>   ground states is $12~u$ exactly, where $u$ is the unified atomic mass
>   unit. The **atomic weight** (also called the relative atomic mass) of
>   isotope $^i\text{E}$ of element $\text{E}$, symbol
>   $A_\text{r}(^i\text{E})$, in material $\text{P}$ is
>
> $A_\text{r}(^i\text{E})
> > =\frac{m_\text{a}(^i\text{E})_\text{P}}{\frac{1}{12}m_\text{a}(\ce{{}^{12}C})}=\frac{m_\text{a}(^i\text{E})_\text{P}}{u}$
>
> Thus, the atomic mass of $\ce{{}^{12}C}$ is $12~u$, and the atomic
>   weight of $\ce{{}^{12}C}$ is $12~$ exactly. All other atomic weight
>   values are ratios to the $\ce{{}^{12}C}$ standard value and thus are
>   dimensionless numbers. The atomic weight of element $\text{E}$,
>   $A_\text{r}(\text{E})$, in a material $\text{P}$ is determined from
>   the relation
>
> $A_\text{r}(\text{E})_\text{P}=\sum\left[x(^i\text{E})_\text{P}\times A_\text{r}(^i\text{E})\right]$
>
> where $x(^i\text{E})_\text{P}$ is the mole fraction of isotope
>   $^i\text{E}$ in material $\text{P}$ (also called the isotopic
>   abundance).

Therefore the standard atomic mass of carbon is (given in an interval)

$m_{\text{a}}(\ce{C})=A_\text{r}(\text{C})_\text{graphite}\times u = [12.0096, 12.0116]u$, with

$u=\frac{1}{12}m_\text{a}(\ce{{}^{12}C})$.

However, the atomic mass of a single molecule is always an integer multiple of $u$.

The molar mass of carbon can then be defined as
\begin{aligned}
M(\ce{C})&=m_{\text{a}}(\ce{C})\times L\\
&=[12.0096, 12.0116]\times10^{-3}~\text{kg/ mol}\\
&\approx 12.01~\text{g/ mol}~\text{(4 s.f.)}
\end{aligned}

The whole relation becomes a little bit clearer when looking at bromine. There are two important Isotopes of bromine: $\ce{^{79}Br}$ and $\ce{^{81}Br}$ ([ref](http://www.webelements.com/bromine/isotopes.html)). So in elemental bromine ($\ce{Br2}$) the molecules may have three different masses $m_{\text{a}}(\ce{^{79}Br2})=158u$, $m_{\text{a}}(\ce{^{81}Br2})=162u$ and $m_{\text{a}}(\ce{^{79}Br^{81}Br})=160u$.

The standard atomic mass of bromine is $m_{\text{a}}(\ce{Br})= [79.901, 79.907]u$. 
Therefore $M(\ce{Br})=[79.901, 79.907]\times 10^{-3}~\text{kg/ mol} \approx 79.90~\text{g/ mol}~\text{(4 s.f.)}$ (based on the reference value).

---

When calculating with molar masses $M$ one always has to keep in mind, that the used standard values are based on a (global) statistic.

---

Related definitions:

[amount of substance](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00297.html), $n$, Also contains definition of: number of moles

> Base quantity in the system of quantities upon which SI is based. It
>   is the number of elementary entities divided by the Avogadro constant.
>   Since it is proportional to the number of entities, the
>   proportionality constant being the reciprocal Avogadro constant and
>   the same for all substances, it has to be treated almost identically
>   with the number of entities. Thus the counted elementary entities must
>   always be specified. The words 'of substance' may be replaced by the
>   specification of the entity, for example: amount of chlorine atoms, 
>   $n_\ce{Cl}$, amount of chlorine molecules,  $n_{\ce{Cl2}}$. No
>   specification of the entity might lead to ambiguities [amount of
>   sulfur could stand for  $n_\ce{S}$,  $n_{\ce{S8}}$, etc.], but in many
>   cases the implied entity is assumed to be known: for molecular
>   compounds it is usually the molecule [e.g. amount of benzene usually
>   means  $n_{\ce{C6H6}}$], for ionic compounds the simplest formula unit
>   [e.g. amount of sodium chloride usually means $n_{\ce{NaCl}}$] and for
>   metals the atom [e.g. amount of silver usually stands for 
>   $n_{\ce{Ag}}$]. In some derived quantities the words 'of substance'
>   are also omitted, e.g. amount concentration, amount fraction. Thus in
>   many cases the name of the base quantity is shortened to amount and to
>   avoid possible confusion with the general meaning of the word the
>   attribute chemical is added. The chemical amount is hence the
>   alternative name for amount of substance. In the field of clinical
>   chemistry the words 'of substance' should not be omitted and
>   abbreviations such as substance concentration (for amount of substance
>   concentration) and substance fraction are in use. The quantity had no
>   name prior to 1969 and was simply referred to as the number of moles.

[relative molecular mass](http://goldbook.iupac.org/R05271.html),  $M_r$

> Ratio of the mass of a molecule to the unified atomic mass unit.
>   Sometimes called the molecular weight or relative molar mass.

[relative molar mass](http://goldbook.iupac.org/R05270.html)
Molar mass divided by  $1~\text{g/ mol} (the latter is sometimes called the standard molar mass).

Answer (score 2):

Like "1 dozen",  "1 mole" refers to an exact number. Molar mass refers to the mass of a very specific number of molecules/atoms: 1 mole. The molar mass is the mass divided by the amount (number of individual entities such as atoms or molecules) of substance measured in *moles*.

[Now 1 mole is equal of course to Avogadro's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit)) $\pu{N_A}$. To make matters clear
$\pu{N_A = 6.022 \times 10^{23}/mol}$
but it is *usually* ok to speak of Avogadro's number as equal to the number of particles in 1 mole. It is therefore fair in practice to make the following substitution when performing computations:

$$\pu{1 mole = N_A = 6.022 \times 10^{23}}$$

withthe understanding that $\pu{N_A}$ always refers to the number of entities in 1 mole.

Now lets say we take 1 mole of carbon-12 atoms and determine its mass. It's $\pu{m = 12.0 g}$, which means the molar mass is

$$\pu{M = 12.0 g/1 mole = 12.0 g/mol}$$

But what if we want to know the mass of 1 atom of $\ce{^{12}C}$? Ok, substitute "1 mole" with Avogadro's number. That's just

$$\pu{M_{molecule} = 12.0 g/N_A = 12.0 g/6.022 \times 10^{23} = 1.66\times 10^{-27} kg = 1.66 yg}$$

But $\pu{1.66\times 10^{-27} kg}$ is a really tiny and cumbersome number, and the "yoctogram" is very rarely used. However we can define an [atomic mass unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_mass_unit):

$$\pu{1 amu = 1 g/N_A (exactly)} $$

Then

$$\pu{M_{molecule} = 12.0 amu}$$

This is much tidier! But that's the same as before, except that we changed "g/mol" with "amu", so the units are practically exchangeable.

However they are not always interchangeable (sometimes you should be careful): the mass of an atom or molecule refers rather obviously to a single atom or molecule, whereas the mass of a mole is a sum over all species in that mole, which may contain for instance a mix of isotopes. Of course, if you refer to an "average mass" then amu and g/mol are interchangeable.

[3]: Actually, chemical engineers distinguish between lb-mol and g-mol and so forth, but I'm a plain chemist, so I stick to chemist's (or SI) convention.

Answer (score 1):

Take the magnitude of formula mass and append "grams" to obtain the mass of one gram-mole.  If  you have a formula weight magnitude and append "pounds," it is one pound-mole.  One gram-mole contains one Avogadro number of formula units.

Like a "dozen eggs," a mole is simply a bigger basket.  It allows you to take microscopic descriptions to real world scales.  Moles are scaling factors for thermodynamics, as in molar volumes of gases.

Comment: I do understand what mole is, but why does 1 mole of an atom/molecule weigh the same as the atomic/molecular mass in grams?

Comment: That is how it is defined through Avogadro's number as the scale factor for a gram-mole.  If the kilogram is redefined as a single crystal silicon ball, Avogadro's constant will be a defined value rather than a measured one.

Answer (score 1):

It is about the definitions, but I suspect you are overcomplicating in thinking it isn't obvious.

A mole is an Avogadro number (6.022 x 10<sup>23</sup>) of things (the *things* could be anything but being a big number it is only a useful metric for atoms and molecules). Given this definition, if a molecule weighs the equivalent of a carbon atom then a mole of it will be 12g. A mole of hydrogen gas weighs about (about because it might have some deuterium) 2g as hydrogen gas consists of H<sub>2</sub> molecules.

Comment: But why is the molecular weight of hydrogen 2 and it's molar weight also 2g?

Comment: One number is the other divided by avogadro's number. Changing the number of molecules or atoms doesn't change the *ratio* of their atomic or molecular weights.

Comment: The Avogadro number is based and therefore the result of the exact definition given by the OP. http://goldbook.iupac.org/M03980.html That is also the reason, why the molecular weights deviate from natural numbers.